# SpringBoot get the list of @RestController i.e List<@RestController> of the application

Tags: java, spring-boot

Small question regarding SpringBoot application, and how to get the list of classes annotated with `@RestController` please.

I have a simple SpringBoot application, where I have couple of my own `@RestController`, such as:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

@RestController
public class OrderController {

@RestController
public class PriceController {
```

But I am also having in my dependencies, in third party libraries I cannot control, some `@RestController` as well.

In my application, I would like to get the list of all the `@RestController`, i.e. all the classes annotated with the annotation `@RestController`. Something like `List<@RestController>`, please note the at sign @, it is not `List<RestController>`

What I have tried so far is to extend all my `@RestController` with a common interface, and get the `List<MyAtRestController>`, but this solution will only limit to the `@RestController` I have control over. Many are in the third party dependencies.

Question, how to get the List of `@RestController` `List<@RestController>` from SpringBoot please?

Thank you

Comment: `applicationContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(RestController.class)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *@Andrey B. Panfilov* has pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74841648/springboot-get-the-list-of-restcontroller-i-e-listrestcontroller-of-the-appl/74841886#comment132080639_74841648), you can inject `ApplicationContext` in any of your Beans and make use of the method [`getBeansWithAnnotation()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html#getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()) to retrieve beans with a particular annotation registered in the context.

*Example:*

```
@Component          // or any other steriotype annotaion
@AllArgsConstructor // to make use of the constractor injection
public class MyBean {
    
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public Collection<Object> getRestControllers() {
    
        Collection<Object> controllers = context
            .getBeansWithAnnotation(RestController.class)
            .values();
        
        return controllers
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. Before I accept, may I ask why is it a ```Collection<Object>``` please? I was hoping to get ```Collection<@RestController>``` or ```Collection<RestController.class>```

Comment: @PatPanda `RestController` (without `@`, it's used when applying annotation) is the type of annotation, and you can annotate any class you need to make a rest controller with `@RestController` but it **doesn't** mean that this class would be bound `RestController` through inheritance. No, they (the *actual controller* and *annotation type*) continue to be independent types. The purpose of annotations is to provide metadata.